# Facebook v3.1 graph api Page Roles edge

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, curl, koala

I'm attempting to get the list of people who have a role on a Facebook Page (graph api edge: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.1/page/roles)

Currently, when using curl and/or rails, I'm not getting anything to return for the edge:

Curl:

```
b@B-MacBook-Pro core (master) $ curl https://graph.facebook.com/v3.1/page_id/roles?access_token=TOKEN

=> {"data":[]}
```

Browser:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v3.1/page_id/roles?access_token=TOKEN

Result:
{
   "data": [

   ]
}
```

Rails:

```
2.5.0 :008 > facebook_page.graph_api.roles(page_id)
 => []
```

The `graph_api.roles(<page_id>)` code is:

```
# Koala.config.api_version = "v3.1"
facebook_connection.graph_call "#{page_id}/roles"
```

This same code worked when using Facebook API v2.9. Since we upgraded to 3.1, we're not getting a anything returned from the edge. I can't/couldn't find anything that tells me the edge was discontinued or shutdown... any help to understand what's happening would be great.

For extra note, I can hit various other edges on v3.1: `locations`, `posts`, `feed`, `place_topics`, `picture`, ect... So I don't believe it's related to my permissions, but I could be wrong I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an outstanding bug:

https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/435435380392240/